# String.replaceAll ignoring regex

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to replace `[br]` with `<br />` in a Java String.

```
someText.replaceAll("\\[br\\]","<br />");
```

This doesn't work at all. I tried removing the backslashes but I got the same result.

Answer (score 12):

Java strings are immutable.  You need to assign the return value back to `someText`:

```
someText = someText.replaceAll("...");
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings are not mutable.  are you handling the *result* of the replaceAll() method calll?